# ELMAH SqlErrorLog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, elmah

I am using Elmah to catch unhandled exceptions in my application.
I would like to run a custom code when Elmah writes a log entry.

I created a custom ErrorLog which is derived from Elmah.SqlErrorLog and I set my ErrorLog in the web config files.

```
namespace Test.Logging
```

{
    public class MySqlErrorLog : Elmah.SqlErrorLog
    {
        public MySqlErrorLog(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString) 
        {

```
    }

    public override string Log(Elmah.Error error)
    {
        return base.Log(error);

        //custom code
    }
}
```

}

```
<errorLog type="Test.Logging.MySqlErrorLog, Test" connectionStringName="elmah-sqlserver" />
```

It seems to be good but nothing happend. There is no log record in the database.

Anybody could help me?

Thanks advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you ever fixed this. Came across your post when trying to fix a similar problem. It turned out I was missing the constructor. In your case, I think it's your namespace that's wrong, the namespace is Test.Logging, not just Test.

So, the web.config line would be:

```
<errorLog type="Test.Logging.MySqlErrorLog, Test.Logging" connectionStringName="elmah-sqlserver" />
```